# Nginx 404's all static content in reverse proxy setup

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, proxy

Whats strange is that this exact configuration used to work fine, but now all static files will 404 on direct link i.e

- domain.com/test.html
- domain.com/test/test.html
- domain.com/ and domain.com/test/ << does work if index.html is present

this is the same for all static filetypes.

Nginx.conf :

```
user www;
worker_processes 8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  sendfile off;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  proxy_cache_path                /web-cache/cache levels=2:2 keys_zone=basic:8m max_size=512m inactive=60m;
  proxy_temp_path                 /web-cache/cache_temp;

  proxy_redirect     off;

  proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout  10m;

  #gzip compression options
  gzip on;
  gzip_static off;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 9;
  gzip_min_length 128;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/xml         application/xml+rss application/javascript application/json;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_vary on;

  # include virtual hosts configuration
  include /etc/nginx/virtual.d/*.conf;
}
```

Virtualhost example :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  access_log off;
  error_log on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6666;
    include /etc/nginx/nocache.conf;
  }
  location ~* ^.+\.(htm|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|bz2|pdf|odt|txt|tar|bmp|rtf|js|swf|avi|mp4|mp3|ogg|flv)$ {
    expires 30d;
    root /home/test/public_html;
  }
}
```

Comment: what's in your logs? did anything change since it was last working?

Comment: Could something in `/etc/nginx/nocache.conf` be breaking config before we get to the regexp location block?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that you have placed `root` inside a `location` block. Best practice is to place it in the `server` block. This is one of the most [common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even after editing the vhost and adding root to the server block and removing the one in location block it is still occurring, any ideas ?.

Comment: To clarify for anyone not bothering to read the linked document: `root` inside a `location` block does work and is valid configuration, but is considered bad practice.

Comment: Still missing the source content of /etc/nginx/nocache.conf

Answer (score 0):

I believe logs will show what files exactly `nginx` tries to pick up.

Possible investigation results are:

1. File exists, but www user doesn't have enough permissions to access it.
2. Nginx uses location `/`